# How to extract a zip file and save files to folder and file name to database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, zip, winrar

How to extract a zip file and save files to folder and file name to database using PHP?

Comment: By googling for a tutorial how to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+extract+zip

Comment: @captaintokyo - if you have to google for all the answers what's the point of this site then?

Comment: To ask questions, not request tutorials that can be found easily by googling or even searching this very same site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$zip = zip_open("xyz.zip");
if ($zip) {
  while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    $fp = fopen("zip/".zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");

    // write the file name zip_entry_name($zip_entry) to DB here

    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
      $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
      fwrite($fp,"$buf");
      zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
      fclose($fp);
    }
  }
  zip_close($zip);
}
```

Comment: no idea, some people just downvote without reading the answer properly.

Comment: Beware that using `zip_entry_read()` with `zip_entry_filesize()` as buffer size will fail for larger files...

Answer (score 4):

This tutorial will teach you how to do this -> http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-open-zip-files-with-php/